# Put a hash tag automatically to publish_stream posts via Facebook APP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to put a hash tag (like # my_app)　on users posts via Facebook API. Will this be Terms violation?

Sample Code:

```
<?php
$message = $_POST('message');
$facebook->api('me/feed', array('message' => $message . ' #my_app'));
```

There is the following description in the terms, is it no problem as long as we notify users before?
(https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#integration)

> If a user grants you a publishing permission, actions you take on the user's behalf must be expected by the user and consistent with the user's actions within your app.

Comment: No, the message content has to be entirely generated by the user themselves (a.k.a. "typed in" in most scenarios). Pre-filling the message or adding to it is not allowed.